# sum of variables in SPSS-statistics25 for multiple external files

Tags: loops, spss, rank

I have 50 external EXCEL files. For each of these files, let's say `#I`,  I import data as it follows in the SYNTAX of SPSS-statistics25:

```
GET DATA /TYPE=XLSX
 /FILE='file#I.xlsx'
 /SHEET=name 'Sheet2'
 /CELLRANGE=full
 /READNAMES=on
 /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
```

Then, I rank the variables included in `#I` file (WA CI) and I select  one single case, at most, as it follows:

```
RANK VARIABLES= WA CI (D) 
  /RANK  
  /PRINT=YES  
  /TIES=LOW.
COUNT SVAR= RWA RCI (1).
SELECT IF( SVAR=2).
EXECUTE.
```

The task is the following:

I should print the sum of values of RWA looping on each EXCEL file `#I`. RWA can have value 1 or can be empty. If there are not selected cases (RWA is empty), the contribution to the sum of values should be 0. The final outcome should be the number of times RWA and RCI have the same TOP rank out of 50 Excel files.

How can I do this in a smart way?

Comment: Would it make sense to stack all the data from the different files into one file, split by source file, and run the rest of the analysis (rank, select etc') just once? You can use a macro to automate `add files` for all the excel files (let me know if you'd like to do that and need help)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your availability. I don't think that having everything in one file will help. At the end, I need to count the number of occurences valued  (1,1) for RWA and RCI. In fact, DATA EDITOR in spss refreshes any time data. So if you have a look at the end you will see in the DATA EDITOR the outcome of the last of the 50 files.  Moreover, my file are well named, they have names like 1.xlsx, 2.xlsx and so on. Therefore it is easy to manage code for each file. The problem is to count 0 or 1 for each file if the case valued (1,1) occurs, accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see the real data files, the following is a little in the dark, but I think it should be a viable strategy (you might as well try :)):

```
* first defining a macro to stack all the files together.
define stackFiles ()
GET DATA /TYPE=XLSX /FILE='file1.xlsx' 
    /SHEET=name 'Sheet2' /CELLRANGE=full /READNAMES=on /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767 /keep WA CI.
compute source=1.
exe.
dataset name gen.
!do !i=2 !to 40
    GET DATA /TYPE=XLSX /FILE=!concat("'file", !i, ".xlsx'")
        /SHEET=name 'Sheet2' /CELLRANGE=full /READNAMES=on /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767/keep WA CI.
    compute source=!i.
    exe.
    add files /file=gen /file=*.
    exe.
!doend.
!enddefine.
* now run the macro.
stackFiles .

* now for the rest of the analysis.
* first split the data by source file, then rank and select.
sort cases by source.
split file by source.
RANK VARIABLES= WA CI (D) /RANK /PRINT=YES /TIES=LOW.
COUNT SVAR= RWA RCI (1).
SELECT IF SVAR=2.
EXECUTE.
```

At this point you have up to 40 rows remaining - 0 or 1 from each original file. You can count or sum using `descriptives RWA.`